# How do you setup npm to install from a GitHub repository that uses Git LFS?

Tags: git

When I run `npm install --save git+ssh://git@github.com:bmahsman/bubblegum.git`, `npm` checks out the text files that `git lfs` puts in place of the actual assets. It appears `npm` isn't using my local user account's `~/.gitconfig`, i.e. the `lfs` filters aren't being used and `git-lfs` is not being called.

I verified that `git-lfs` and `git lfs` work from both `cmd` and `bash`. I tried the above `npm install` command in both `cmd` and `bash` and I get the same result. I verified that `git clone git@github.com:bmahsman/bubblegum.git` from scratch produces the actual binary files instead of the text files.

My repo is located at `https://github.com/bmahsman/bubblegum` and I use Git LFS to manage binary art and sound assets, so it has a `.gitattributes` modified with `git lfs track`:

```
$ cat ./.gitattributes
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogv filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

My local user account is configured for `git` this way:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = Brynn Mahsman
    email = brynn.mahsman@gmail.com
[merge]
    ff = no
[credential]
    helper = cache
[alias]
    sc = git clone --recursive
    sp = push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
    su = submodule update --remote --merge
[push]
    default = simple
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
```

I'm using Windows 7.

```
$ npm -v
2.14.7

$ git --version
git version 2.6.2.windows.1
```

edit: In case this is a bug, I've made an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10857).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(This is not an answer. It was supposed to be a comment on the question, but this account doesn't have the reputation to comment yet. Sorry about that.)</sub>

This looks like a bug in npm. I don't see anything you're doing wrong. [Try here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I have made an issue on GitHub for both the git-lfs and npm projects.

Answer (score 0):

After poring over the output from `git` and `npm` with `export GIT_TRACE=1` and `npm config loglevel verbose`, I believe I have figured out how to get this to work, at least with GitLab (I have since moved from GitHub to GitLab, which also supports Git LFS).

Step 1. Inside of your repository, run the following command (replace `bubblegum` with the name of your repo) and then commit the resulting `.gitconfig` and push:

`$ git config -f .gitconfig lfs.url https://gitlab.com/brynn.mahsman/bubblegum.git/info/lfs`

Step 2. In the directory in which you want to `npm install` your project, run for example:

`$ npm install -S https://gitlab.com/brynn.mahsman/bubblegum.git`

---

For this to work with GitHub, it would appear that the `lfs.url` to use is: `https://api.github.com/lfs/<user or organization>/<repository name>`, e.g.:

`$ git config -f .gitconfig lfs.url https://api.github.com/lfs/brynn.mahsman/bubblegum`

---

You may want to install a credential manager so that you don't have to enter your username and password every time `git-lfs` goes to retrieve a file. For Windows, I use [Microsoft's credential manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).

---

The `.gitconfig` you commit to the repository allows the git commands used by `npm install` to know what `lfs.url` to use. I'm not sure if this solution only masks the fact that `npm install` can't figure out the `lfs.url` without you explicitly specifying it in `.gitconfig`. In other words, when I run the command `git clone https://gitlab.com/brynn.mahsman/bubblegum.git`, `git` somehow knows the `lfs.url` even if I don't have the `.gitconfig` in the repository.